# Dose self.class.class_eval equal to instance_eval?

Tags: ruby

I want to find out the difference between instance_eval and class_eval,so i did some work。After searching the internet， I figure out something， but there comes an other question I can't understand！When I'm doing this:

```
class FindMe

  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    method = method.to_s
    self.class.class_eval <<-EOF, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{method}
        puts "I'm an instance method! I'm #{method}"
      end
    EOF
    send method, *args
  end

  def self.method_missing method, *args, &block
    method = method.to_s
    instance_eval <<-HERE, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{method}
        puts "I'm a class method! I'm #{method}"
      end
    HERE
    send method, *args
  end

end

FindMe.new.hello
FindMe.hello
```

I get

```
I'm an instance method! I'm hello
I'm a class method! I'm hello
```

When I change my code to :

```
class FindMe

  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    method = method.to_s
    self.class.class_eval <<-EOF, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{method}
        puts "I'm an instance method! I'm #{method}"
      end
    EOF
    send method, *args
  end

  def self.method_missing method, *args, &block
    method = method.to_s
    self.class.class_eval <<-HERE, __FILE__, __LINE__
      def #{method}
        puts "I'm a class method! I'm #{method}"
      end
    HERE
    send method, *args
  end

end

FindMe.new.hello
FindMe.hello
```

I get the same output, Can any one tell what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `class_eval` you modify the class, by `instance_eval` the current instance only. Look:

```
▶ class A
▷   def ceval
▷     self.class.class_eval "def on_class ; puts 'On Class' ; end"
▷   end
▷   def ieval
▷     self.instance_eval "def on_instance ; puts 'On Instance' ; end"
▷   end
▷ end
▶ a1 = A.new
#⇒ #<A:0xcf6a87c>
▶ a1.ceval
#⇒ :on_class
▶ a1.ieval
#⇒ :on_instance
▶ a1.on_class
#⇒ On Class
▶ a1.on_instance
#⇒ On Instance

▶ a2 = A.new
#⇒ #<A:0xd0e9f7c>
▶ a2.on_class
#⇒ On Class  !!! IT IS DEFINED ON NEWLY CREATED INSTANCE OF A
▶ a2.on_instance
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `on_instance' for #<A:0xd0e9f7c>
```

The latter fails because we declare `on_instance` method **on instance `a1`**, and `a2` knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

See this example, and try explain to yourself:

```
class Foo
  def a
    self.class.class_eval <<-EOS
      def x
        'This is an instance method.'
      end
    EOS
  end

  def b
    self.instance_eval <<-EOS
      def y
        'This is a singleton method.'
      end
    EOS
  end
end

foo1 = Foo.new
foo2 = Foo.new

foo1.a
foo1.b

foo1.x  #=> This is an instance method.
foo1.y  #=> This is a singleton method.

foo2.x  #=> This is an instance method.
foo2.y  #=> NoMethodError
```